# How to send out monthly mail with csv file from Save Data Adapter using PloneFormGen?

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I would like to send out a monthly mail containing the csv as stored by the [Save Data Adapter](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/ploneformgen/getting_started.html#the-save-data-adapter) of PloneFormGen. The csv file should be an attachment of this mail. After the mail is sent out, the Save Data Adapter should be cleared. Is this possible?

The idea is basically to automatically have a monthly summary of all registrations done via PloneFormGen which can then easily be imported into external tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were doing this, I'd set it up as a Python "run" script that would be run as a monthly cron job.

Run scripts are normal Python scripts, run via commands like:

```
bin/client5 run myscript.py
```

They reveal the top of the ZMI as "app". Check PloneFormGen's source for the save-data adapter. It has methods for getting and setting the saved data. After that, it's routine scripting.

Comment: Does `bin/client5` mean that the site must be ZEO based? Or would this approach also be possible using a standalone (`bin/instance` only) setup?

Comment: Ok, found the answer [here](http://developer.plone.org/misc/commandline.html): _"Note: If the site runs in a single process Zope mode (no ZEO), the actual site instance must be stopped to run a command line script as the one process locks the database (Data.fs)."_